# REST JSON Service using Entity framework 6

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, wcf, entity-framework

**Problem**

I have a database in SQL Server. I want to use Entity framework 6 for the CRUD Operations and expose them through WCF Service so I can consume them in an Android Application and ASP.Net Application.

The problem although is that I cannot send the EF generated entities over the WCF Services (Even after setting the Data Contract and Data Member Attributes). Something I dont want to do is to create separate DTOs as they will limit the benefit of the EF as I will have to change them every time I change the database.

I have looked into WCF Data Services but I dont want the clients to query the database directly but to expose some methods, which can perform the CRUD operations, Return Lists of a single entity and so on. Microsoft here isn't recommending Self - Tracking entities : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613668.aspx

I will be having a 2 Tier Application, with one hosting the WCF and EF and the other being the Presentation Tier (ASP.Net Website and Android App).

My Question is, How and Which is the Best way to accomplish this task, without limiting the flexibility provided by EF 6.

Comment: You can use POCO entities. But what is the use of self tracking entities if you want to pass them to an Android application?

Comment: I dont want to use self-tracking entities. What I am looking for is some way to pass the entities created by the EF to the Android Application through the WCF Service in JSON format.

Comment: Are you dead set on using WCF? Otherwise you could use WebApi's from MVC, which makes it very simple. Otherwise there is a DataContractJsonSerializer or JavaScriptSerializer

Comment: I would prefer WCF if its possible through it. Can u guide me about DataContractJsonSerializer?